# Selenium regex question

Tags: selenium

Im trying to automate the creation of a customer on the project im currently workin on, using selenium. (note, so far im only using selenium's own ide, not through java or anything else) The problem im having is that the panel i use to fill in the details is not recognised on playback of the script. This is because the panel gets a new id every time it is generated, and selenium is looking for the old one. I wanna know can i use regex somehow to match the pattern of the id instead of the actual id?

The ID looks something like this: P_0500A_72_4_P
its only the 4 that increments. and if a new browser session is started it resets to 72_0 and begins to increment again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not mentioned what element the panel is. Assuming this to be a div, your html element should be something like given below

```
<div id="P_0500A_72_4_P">
<div id="P_0500A_72_5_P">
```

To identify the div use the following xpath:

```
"//div[contains(@id,'P_0500A_72_')]"
```

This xpath will select the element which has P_0500A_72_ in its ID.

Comment: My bad, im still new this whole web based stuff.  That allows me to find the outside frame just fiine. but how about the individual text input fields inside it?

Comment: Can you show the HTML code for this individual text input field? It will help us in providing better answers

Comment: I noticed that each input field has its own identifier after it, eg the name field has _CUSTNAME , language has LANGCODE. can that xpath be configured to look for those instead? i think that would solve my problem

Comment: yes you can configure that too. like "//input[contains(@id,'_CUSTNAME')]"